# Configure the Domain attributes of the cookie header withing the spring or spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

How to configure the Domain  attributes of the cookie withing the spring security java config.
I need to restrict access of  a cookie to only one particular subdomin something like

```
Domain=.test.example.com;
```

Now i know that there is a xml config looking like the sample below, however i do not jave any web.xml in my application anymore and i want to have all my configuration made trough java.

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>400</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <name>KSESSION</name>
        <path>/</path>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

In my SecurityConfig class which  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter i was searching for some session-config object or parameter but i can no find one i.e. i have only the sessionManagement object.

```
    .sessionManagement()
        .enableSessionUrlRewriting(false)

        .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionControlStrategy())
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
        .sessionFixation().newSession()

        .maximumSessions(1)
        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
        .expiredUrl("/login?expired")
```

Maybe that is done trough the TomcatContextCustomizer bean  i.e. i found there the parameter  setUseHttpOnly and  path parameters there but no setter on the domain attribute.

```
@Bean 
public TomcatContextCustomizer tomcatContextCustomizer() {
    System.out.println("TOMCATCONTEXTCUSTOMIZER INITILIZED");
    return new TomcatContextCustomizer() {

    @Override
    public void customize(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        context.addServletContainerInitializer(new WsSci(), null);
        context.setUseHttpOnly(true);
        context.setPath("/testBlaBlaPage");



    }
};
```

}

So basically my target is to have a http header like that

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONCookie: JSESSIONID=DEAC4422AB4E28A7062C08724C8BCFAA; Path=/login; Secure; Domain=.test.example.com; HttpOnly.
```

currently it looks like

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONCookie: JSESSIONID=DEAC4422AB4E28A7062C08724C8BCFAA; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
```

Answer (score 3):

ok i found the answer to my quesiton i.e. it is the method  setSessionCookieDomain() under the tomcat context. i.e. something like

context.setSessionCookieDomain(".test.example.com");